# Show current "setterm" values/settings

Tags: terminal, console

I know that `setterm` can be used to adjust parameters such as screen blanking time on a virtual console. How can I show the current `setterm` settings/values for all parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The least one can say is that the interface to set those VT attributes is very messy. Some are done with [ioctls](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_console.2.html) (a myriad of them), some with [escape sequences](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) (some that affect one VT some all at once), some are also accessible via `/sys`...

For the blanking time, you can have a look at `/sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank`  (in seconds).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer suggests that there is no single place where all the settings are stored or viewable?

Comment: Yes, in this instance, it is set with an escape sequence (`printf '\033[9;10]'` to set a 10 **minute** blank time) which you can read as `600` seconds in a `/sys` file (though it can be set by the `/sys` file as well), some are done by ioctls. There might be a command to query all of them the same way as `setterm` can be used to **set** some of them, but I don't know what that is. And there's nothing in util-linux where setterm comes from.

Comment: I have the exact same question but I'm not seeing this path/file on my CentOS 5.x server.  There doesn't appear to be a `kernel` sub-directory under `/sys/module/`.  There are plenty of other directories though.  Would this consoleblank param exist somewhere else?

Comment: @MikeB, you need kernel 2.6.31 (2009) or above, CentOS 5 is using 2.6.18 (2006) I believe.